# how to store an array in PHP $_COOKIE value

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

i want to store an array of strings in a PHP cookie 
example :

```
$array = array("1", "test");
setcookie($cookie_name, $array, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array('a'=>"1", 2=>"test", 25);
$json = json_encode($array);
setcookie('name', $json);
array = json_decode($_COOKIE['name']);
```

Comment: thanks , that's helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it into a string (e.g. http_build_query($array) or serialize) and store it in the cookie and then again to read from it you can parse the string (e.g. str_parse($_Cookie['cookie']) or deserialize).

Comment: what means to parse and serialize please ?

Comment: There are some methods to convert an array to a string. http_build_query or serialize are methods to convert this. Then you want to convert the string back to an array which you can user str_parse if you converted the array using http_build_query or unserialize if you've used serialize method.
$array = array("1", "test");
setcookie($cookie_name, serialize($array), time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
$array = unserialize($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);

Comment: thanks , that's helpful :)